# Removing a commit in remote from local

Tags: git, github, android-source, gerrit

I'm currently working with git on building aosp. The task I wish to perform is removing a commit from my local that's already been pushed to the remote by someone else.

After some heavy Googling I came across `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, which I thought did what I wanted it to do after typing `git log` and not seeing the commit.

When I went to `brunch` the build, it failed, stating that the build at the change wasn't clean.
Noting that I'd completed a build only 30mins prior to this, I know the initial build wasn't the issue.

Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the commit completely or just revert back, create a branch to work locally on something?

Comment: Ultimately, what I'm trying to determine is which commit caused the issue in the remote branch.
Whatever way I have to go about that is not really an issue for me.

Should the correct way be to create a local branch and build off that for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can revert to a previous commit by using [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem--detachltcommitgt) command, `git checkout` accepts commit hash/ID, just run `git log` search for the commit you want to revert to and copy the previous commit hash and run the following command:

```
git checkout COMMIT_HASH   # This will revert back git history just before the commit
```

And after that if you want to go back to just run

```
git checkout HEAD
```